# Cannot open gnome-control-center in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, settings, gnome-control-center

I cannot open the settings from the applications and also cannot open from terminal by typing gnome-control-center. Trying to open it from terminal gives the following error:

`gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: libpop-upgrade-gtk-ffi.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have searched for this library and cannot seem to find it. I also went through other similar issues, but none seem to have this problem of missing this particular file.

Answer (score 6):

Was able to fix the issue by removing Pop!_OS PPA and reinstalling `gnome-control-center`.

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:system76/pop`

Then reinstall gnome-control-center:

`sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center`

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 too. What happened to mine is that I installed `pop-theme` via terminal so I added Pop!_OS repositories and that broke my Settings app somehow. Reinstalling `gnome-control-center` just grabs it from System76 so we have to remove their PPA so we can grab the one from Ubuntu.

If that did not work, you might have to remove `pop-upgrade` too before reinstalling `gnome-control-center`.

`sudo apt remove --purge pop-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: unfortunately, this did not solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me

Comment: I had to do the purge thing. Then it worked for me.